Checking if the operator $Tf(s)= \int_{s^2}^{\infty }\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$ is continuous.
Let the operator $T:L^2(0,+\infty )\to L^2(1,+\infty )$ be defined by $$Tf(s)= \int_{s^2}^{\infty }\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$$ To check continuity I decided to find the norm $\| T\| =\text{sup}_{\| f\| =1}\| Tf\| $.
$$\begin{split} \left\| \int_{s^2}^{\infty }\frac{f(t)}{t}dt \right\| & =\left( \int_{1}^{\infty }\left( \left| \int_{s^2}^{\infty }\frac{f(t)}{t}dt) \right| \right)^2 \right)^{1/2}\\
&\overset{\text{Hölder}}{\le} \left( \int_{1}^{\infty }\left(\int_{s^2}^{\infty }\left|f(t)\right|^2dt)\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{s^2}^{\infty }\left|\frac{1}{t}\right|^2dt) \right)^{1/2}d\mu \right)^{1/2} \\ &\le \left[ \int_{1}^{\infty }\left( \frac{1}{s^2} \right)^{1/2}ds \right]^{1/2}=\infty \end{split}$$
But I can't find a lower bound, can anyone suggest how to find it?

$|Tf(s)|\le |f|\frac 1 s$.

The inner $1/2$ exponents on the second line shouldn't be there since there's an inner square in the first line.

@Bruno yes you're right, then the upper bound must be 1? How to prove the norm is equal to 1?

The operator $T$ can be considered as $T:L^2(1,\infty)\to L^2(1,\infty)$ as it vanishes on functions $f$ whose support is contained in $(0,1).$ The operator is of the form
$$(Tf)(s)=\int\limits_1^\infty K(s,t)f(t)\,dt$$ where
$K(s,t)={1\over t}{\bf 1}_{[s^2,\infty)}(t).$ It is well known  that $T$ is bounded if $K(s,t)$ is square integrable on $[1,\infty)\times [1,\infty)$ and
$$\|T\|\le \|K\|_2:=\left (\int\limits_1^\infty \int\limits_1^\infty|K(s,t)|^2\,dt\,ds\right )^{1/2}$$
The proof can be made by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality two times.
In our case we have
$$\|K\|_2^2=\int\limits_1^\infty\int\limits_{s^2}^\infty {1\over t^2}\,dt\,ds= \int\limits_1^\infty{1\over s^2}=1$$
Thus $\|T\|\le 1.$
Remark The operator $T$ belongs to the Hilbert-Schmidt class of compact operators. Its norm is actually strictly less then $1.$ To this end we can show that the adjoint operator $T^*$ corresponds to $K^*(s,t)=K(t,s).$ Furthermore, the operator $T^*T$ corresponds to  $$\widetilde{K}(s,t)=\int\limits_1^\infty K^*(s,x)K(x,t)\,dx=\int\limits_1^\infty K(x,s)K(x,t)\,dx\\ ={1\over st}[\min(t^{1/2},s^{1/2})-1] 
$$
We have $$\int\limits_1^\infty\int\limits_1^\infty {1\over s^2t^2}[\min(t^{1/2},s^{1,2})-1]^2\,ds\,dt  \\ =2\int\limits_1^\infty\int\limits_t^\infty {1\over s^2t^2}[t^{1,2}-1]^2\,ds\,dt
=2\int\limits_1^\infty{1\over t^3}[t^{1/2}-1]^2\,dt={1\over 3}$$ Thus
$$\|T\|=\|T^*T\|^{1/2}\le {1\over \sqrt{3}}$$

The operator $T$ in the OP can be viewed as a composition of operators:

the adjoint operator of the Hardy operator $H:L_p(0,\infty)\rightarrow L_p(0,\infty)$, $1<p<\infty$,  defined as $(Hf)(x)=\frac1x\int^x_0 f(s)\,ds$, namely
$$(H^*f)(t)=\int^\infty_t \frac{f(y)}{y}\,dy$$
It is known that
$$\|H\|_2=\|H^*\|_2=2$$

$A:L_p(0,\infty)\rightarrow L_p(1,\infty)$ define as $(Af)(s)=\mathbb{1}_{(1,\infty)}(s)f(s^2)$. Notice that
$$\|Af\|^2_{L_2(1,\infty)}=\int^\infty_1|f(s^2)|^2\,ds=\frac12\int^\infty_1|f(u)|^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\,du\leq\frac12\|f\|^2_{L_2(0,\infty)}
$$


Observe that $T=A\circ H^*$. Hence $\|T\|\leq\|A\|\,\|H^*\|$.

You get the estimate $|T|\le \sqrt{2}$ while $|T|\le 1.$
